# When I load my filedisk driver, I got the ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND(127) error code

Tags: windows, winapi, driver

I want to develop an *encrypt-virtual-disk* based on the *FileDisk-17* opensource project.

Here is my solution:

In `IPR_MJ_READ`, when the `ZwReadFile` returns, I use function '`DecryptData`' to decrypt the data read by `ZwReadFile`.

In `IPR_MJ_WRITE`, before call `ZwWriteFile`, I use function '`EncryptData`' to encrypt the data which will be written to the disk.

I put `EncryptData` & `DecryptData` functions in a single C source file.

The question is; when I loaded my driver, I get the `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND(127)` error code 
every time, even there are only one line in the `EncryptData` or `DecryptData` function.

Who can tell me what caused this and how to fix it?

### filedisk.c

```
switch (io_stack->MajorFunction)
        {
        case IRP_MJ_READ:
            system_buffer = (PUCHAR) MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(irp->MdlAddress, NormalPagePriority);
            if (system_buffer == NULL)
            {
                irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
                irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
                break;
            }
            buffer = (PUCHAR) ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, io_stack->Parameters.Read.Length);
            if (buffer == NULL)
            {
                irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
                irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
                break;
            }
            ZwReadFile(
                device_extension->file_handle,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                &irp->IoStatus,
                buffer,
                io_stack->Parameters.Read.Length,
                &io_stack->Parameters.Read.ByteOffset,
                NULL
                );
            *if(bEncrypt)
            {
                cipher = (PUCHAR)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, irp->IoStatus.Information, 'TAG');
                if(cipher)
                {   
                    **DecryptData**(buffer, cipher, irp->IoStatus.Information);
                    RtlCopyMemory(system_buffer, cipher, irp->IoStatus.Information);
                    ExFreePool(cipher);
                }
                else
                {
                    irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
                    irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }*
            else
            {
                RtlCopyMemory(system_buffer, buffer, io_stack->Parameters.Read.Length);
                ExFreePool(buffer);
            }
```

---

crypto.c

```
    VOID EncryptData(PUCHAR src, PUCHAR dst, ULONG length)
{
    BF_LONG data[2];
    BF_KEY  key;

    BF_set_key(&key, pCryptoInformation->CryptoKey, sizeof(pCryptoInformation->CryptoKey));
}

VOID DecryptData(PUCHAR src, PUCHAR dst, ULONG length)
{
    BF_LONG data[2];
    BF_KEY  key;

    BF_set_key(&key, pCryptoInformation->CryptoKey, sizeof(pCryptoInformation->CryptoKey));
}
```

Comment: Is `crypto.c` statically linked into the driver?  Are you using the right build tool, i.e., the Windows DDK?  Have you successfully built the unmodified project?

Comment: I added the 'crypto.c' into the SOURCES part of the Source file, like this: 'SOURCES=filedisk.c filedisk.rc bf_skey.c bf_enc.c crypto.c'; I uses the DDK's build tool and the DDK's version is 7600.16385.1.

Comment: So if you take the calls to EncryptData and DecryptData out, does the driver then load properly?  Are the functions properly labelled as non-pageable?

Comment: Have you successfully built and loaded the unmodified project?

Comment: Yes, I can loaded the unmodified project successfully. Yesterday, I commented a pre-process instruction:#pragma code_seg(), when I load the driver, I got a system crash with PAGE_FALUT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA error code. I uncommented the #pragma code_seg() pre-process instruction and deleted all code inside the EncryptData and DecryptData functions, the driver can loaded successfully. Is this a PAGED problem?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it.  If removing the code in EncryptData/DecryptData resolved the problem, the problem is probably something to do with BF_set_key.  What if you put the call to BF_set_key back in but remove the code in BF_set_key?  I assume you've turned off all compiler optimizations?

Comment: Hold on ... when you commented out the `#pragma` the driver would successfully load?  That does suggest the problem is something to do with the segmentation.  Give me a moment.

Comment: OK, having refreshed my memory, I don't believe commenting out `#pragma code_seg()` would cause a page fault unless there was a previous `#pragma` that changed the current segment.  Try commenting out all segment-related `#pragma` commands and see what happens.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I commented the code one by one of the DecryptData and EncryptData function. Finally, I found that it is the BF_KEY casued the problem. Whether I commented all of the '#pragma', the driver can loaded successfully, but if I uncommented the 'BF_KEY', the ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND happed. The BF_KEY is defined  like this: `typedef struct bf_key_st
{
 BF_LONG P[BF_ROUNDS+2];
 BF_LONG S[4*256];
} BF_KEY;` In Windows Server 2003 R2, `sizeof(BF_KEY)=4168`. Is The BF_KEY larger than the maximum stack space in driver-mode?

Comment: It probably shouldn't be on the stack, no, but I'm puzzled as to how that would cause a load-time error.  Random thought: try renaming the `EncryptData` and `DecryptData` functions, just in case there's a naming conflict.